# TeXmaker keyboard shortcuts not working

Tags: texmaker

I just installed Texmaker 5.1.4 today (Win 10) and the quick build keyboard shortcut isn't working. In fact, none of the shortcuts appear to be functioning at all. I rebound the quick build shortcut to Ctrl + T since I'm very accustomed to that from TeXworks, but I tried the original F1 binding as well and nothing works.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?